# How to hide other div apart from touched div to the band

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide other `divs` apart from touched div to the band

the band is this element  `<div class="center-band"></div>`

**whenever the scrolling element `touches` the element `<div class="center-band"></div>` then it has to be shown, and other divs have to be hidden**

**Question:** only `touched` `div` to the `band` has to be shown, and others has to be `hidden`, that means only one `content` has to be shown at a time.

**jsbin:** https://jsbin.com/zudideheza/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```js
$(function()
{
    var pos = 1;
    var ii = 0;

    var intId = setInterval(function()
    {
        ii++;
        pos = - ii;
        //console.log(pos);

        $('.container').css({
            transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000d6;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #a19999;
    position: relative;
}

.contents {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 20px;
}

.center-band {
    width: 98%;
    height: 78px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #b4b1b147;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container" style="transform:translateY(0px);">
  <div class="contents"> (1)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
  <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
  <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
  <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
  <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
  <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
  <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
  <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
  <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
  <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>      
</div>

<div class="center-band"></div>

</div>
```

**Note:** I don't want to change scrolling content approach (question is not about positioning)

Please help me thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this out:

```js
$(function()
{
var pos = 1;
var ii = 0;



var intId = setInterval(function()
{
    ii++;
    pos = - ii;
    //console.log(pos);

    $('.inner-content').css({
        transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
    });


}, 100);
});
```

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000d6;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #a19999;
    position: relative;
}

.contents {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
    padding: 20px;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
}
.show{
    /*visibility: visible;*/
}

.center-band {
    width: 98%;
    height: 78px;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #b4b1b147;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class=" center-band"  style="overflow-y:hidden;">

      <div class="inner-content" style=" transform:translateY(0px);">
        <div class="contents"> (1)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
        <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
        <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
        <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
        <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
        <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
        <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
        <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
        <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
        <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>    
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: My question is simple,  instead of `visibility:hidden` can't I use `display:none` without `flashing`?

Comment: no `display:none` element has no height or width when it's hidden that's why you can't do this effect on it.

Comment: if its visiblity is hidden it will jump in my teleprompter screen, thats why i need **no height and width for hidden elements**

Comment: please help me with this?

Comment: you don't want them to take space outside the black box?

Comment: I edited my answer take a look and tell me if that's something like you wanted

Comment: you understood me wrongly , now your updated code shows only contents within band ,  rather it has to show whole div content, see my expected output: http://jsfiddle.net/kofp4x38/2/

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the direct answer to your questions, but another approach to solve this. May be this will help you somehow.

```js
var domRect = document.getElementById('center-band').getBoundingClientRect();
var centerBandTop = domRect.top+20;
var centerBandBottom = domRect.top + 58;

$(function(){
   var pos = 1;
   var ii = 0;
   var intId = setInterval(function(){
    ii++;
    pos =- ii;
    $('.container').css({
         transform   :  'translateY('+pos+'px)'
    });
  

    $('.contents').each(function(idx,ele){
         var domContent = document.getElementsByClassName('contents')[idx].getBoundingClientRect();
        // console.log(idx +'---'+  domContent.top) 
         if(domContent.top < centerBandBottom && domContent.bottom > centerBandTop ){
                 //$(ele).text('');
         }
         else{
                //$(ele).css('color','#fff');
         }
  })
   },100);
});
```

```css
.container{
z-index:999;
   width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background: #222;*/
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #222;
    position: relative;
}

.contents{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
   /* border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;*/
    padding: 20px;
    color:#fff;
}

#center-band{
    width: 98%;
    height: 78px;
    
    background: #222;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container" style="transform:translateY(0px);">
  <div class="contents"> (1)  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus fugit eius perferendis veritatis accusantium corporis nulla alias sed possimus quibusdam reiciendis nisi maiores inventore error, incidunt eveniet ut asperiores officiis.</div>
  <div class="contents">(2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima, distinctio temporibus facere, laboriosam doloribus error quaerat ipsa, non nobis rerum mollitia quibusdam quas illo a qui consequuntur consectetur deleniti saepe.</div>
  <div class="contents">(3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde, sed, atque. Adipisci quasi debitis, soluta praesentium distinctio impedit veritatis officia molestias culpa fuga excepturi voluptates suscipit aliquam ea unde, non!</div>
  <div class="contents">(4) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, incidunt, harum. Perferendis ipsum, molestias nihil sequi nam nulla, aliquid ipsa numquam cum! Perferendis ut voluptates hic excepturi dolores, ipsum impedit.</div>
  <div class="contents">(5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim itaque debitis voluptates, reiciendis dolorum, labore eius. Illum similique ex, iusto rerum ratione minima, corporis aspernatur aliquam, itaque numquam sint enim!</div>
  <div class="contents">(6) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint numquam totam, a aliquam veritatis porro ullam! Nostrum sint ipsum odio aperiam deserunt aut placeat dignissimos est ad, quae vitae aliquid.</div>
  <div class="contents">(7) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quos atque enim, alias culpa quibusdam ratione, beatae non possimus, velit eaque. Optio qui saepe, earum harum beatae maxime obcaecati minima.</div>
  <div class="contents">(8) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic id incidunt sapiente, magni, sequi ea molestiae iure maxime delectus doloribus error assumenda veritatis maiores saepe nihil neque autem similique obcaecati!</div>
  <div class="contents">(9) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum velit hic iure nam nulla natus corrupti eveniet, suscipit voluptates nostrum. Cupiditate vero ipsam alias fuga, magnam voluptas deserunt corporis non!</div>
  <div class="contents">(10) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae voluptatibus accusamus pariatur? Ipsum nobis ratione fuga, voluptates quam placeat officia odit eveniet aliquam, eaque quisquam tenetur! Exercitationem maxime vel quas!</div>
  
</div>
    <div id="center-band"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is about to solve the problem , but not working correctly, rather than hiding can you please change color of `contents` that touches `band`

Comment: i think using this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect or https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getboundingclientrect.asp , it can be possible but **i'm unable to achieve the solution still** - **Please help me**

Comment: My question is simple,  instead of `visibility:hidden` can't I use `display:none` without `flashing`?

Comment: You can't use `display:none`. In my approach I have used color changing.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to include the margins or not, but you can use the following to detect the positions and then apply the class `over` to the `.content` divs that are currently hovered over:

```
$(function() {
  var pos = 1;
  var ii = 0;

  var centerbandTop = $('.center-band').offset().top;
  var centerbandBottom = $('.center-band').outerHeight() + centerbandTop;

  var intId = setInterval(function() {
    ii++;
    pos = -ii;

    $('.contents').each(function() {
      var $content = $(this);
      var contentTop = $content.offset().top;
      var contentBottom = $content.outerHeight() + contentTop;

      $content.removeClass('over');

      if (centerbandBottom > contentTop && centerbandTop < contentBottom)
        $content.addClass('over');
    });

    $('.container').css({
      // '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(0,' + pos + ')',
      transform: 'translateY(' + pos + 'px)'
    });

  }, 100);
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/YwaPy3qz07goW5ZfwARl

Comment: To hide rather than highlight, replace `$content.removeClass('over');` with `$content.css('visibility', 'hidden');` and `$content.addClass('over');` with `$content.css('visibility', 'visible');`

Comment: Updated Plunk to match (also set visibility of .contents to hidden at the start)

Comment: @K Scandrett, i liked your answer the most , one small **Request** can't i use `display:none`  rather than `visibility:hidden`, so that i can avoid **content jump in real scenario**  - i have tried with `$content.show(),$content.hide()` but did not work,. **Please help me**

Comment: @skBangalore you won't be able to use `display:none` because this collapses the height of the content divs, so they will never be under the band. By content jump do you mean you only want to see text in the band, with the remainder of the `.content` div currently showing outside of it hidden from view?

Comment: Something like this might do the trick? http://plnkr.co/edit/wMDEZKArgk19VPyQ1PxX?p=info

Comment: @ K Scandrett, `Scroll` approach does not work for me as i'm working on **big** project, even `scroll` is not detected. with the existing above approach (first solution) can't i `hide/show` **contents** without **flashing**

Comment: @skBangalore I'm still not clear from your description what problem you want solved

Comment: Jumping off the screen,  when some content is added so,  I just wanted to hide all divs except touching band, without using scroll and avoiding flashing,  thank you

Comment: My question is simple,  instead of `visibility:hidden` can't I use `display:none` without `flashing`?

Comment: Have you set `visibility: hidden` in the CSS for `.contents` (see my original plunk)?  There should be no flashing when starting or adding new content divs as long as you have this